# How do I copy a track (GPX) from Garmin Explore to GPSMap 66?

Tags: gps

I have imported a track (GPX) into the Garmin Explore application on my Android smartphone, and paired the smartphone with my GPSMap 66s (by first pairing with Garmin Connect, then with Garmin Explore).  The device is shown as connected in Garmin Explore under "Devices" and the tracks I want to copy are visible in Garmin Explore under "Tracks".  The GPSMap shows a Bluetooth symbol and some of my tracks have evidently been copied from the GPSMap to the smartphone (after ~4 hours of syncing, around 50 tracks are visible in Garmin Explore).  How do I now copy/sync those tracks from the smartphone to the GPSMap 66s?  The [Garmin support page](https://support.garmin.com/en-US/?faq=Om0zJvBOJ2897CT2dvcFm5) suggests this should happen automatically, but the tracks are not shown in the track list, and when I mount the device, there are no new files on the file system after about four hours (perhaps I need to wait longer?).

How do I copy a GPX file from the Garmin Explore application to the GPSMap 66?

Solutions with other smartphone applications are also welcome.

Comment: Did you connect with [Garmin Connect](https://support.garmin.com/en-US/?faq=xnxBqawGRp0vickWJHl1d6&searchQuery=pairing%20gpsmap%20with%20phone&textPage=2) first? Have you tried [these steps?](https://support.garmin.com/en-US/?faq=ANpwZFBixI5Z0Z3eYMxPf6&searchQuery=pairing%20gpsmap%20with%20phone&textPage=2)

Comment: @bob1 Yes; it does seem to be syncing, but extremely slowly (50 tracks in 4 hours) and only from the Garmin to the smartphone, not the other way around.

Comment: That is incredibly slow I would have thought. Given that it is bluetooth is should be 700 kb/s - 25 Mb/s (depending on variety of BT), so unless they are very big files, it should be a lot faster than that.

Comment: @bob1 Yes, it is.  I suspect the app is just bad.  The Garmin Explore app gets some very bad reviews on Google Play.  50 tracks should take seconds, not hours.  I'm going to explore a cabled approach.